# skipping index 3 of items while inserting in map

Tags: c++11, greedy

why index 3 item is not getting inserted in map?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
  double maximumValue (vector<pair<int, int>>& items, int n, int w) {
     map<double,int,greater<double>>mp;
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       mp.insert ({(items[i].second / (double)items[i].first), i });
     }
 }
```

Skipping index 3 of items for input

```
8 150
30 2 50 **37** 97 26 77 85 weight
30 50 2 **37** 85 77 26 97 value
```

why index 3 item is not getting inserted in map?

Comment: Both `30/30` and `37/37` have the same value `1`. In effect, you are doing `mp.insert({1, 0}); mp.insert({1, 3});` A `std::map` can only contain a given key once, so the second `insert` call does nothing. Perhaps you've chosen a wrong data structure for the problem.